# How to build lambda architecture with Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

we are building a lambda architecture with spark structured streaming. we plan to run the Batch job behind by about 8 hours and the streaming part every 30 seconds or so.

One part that has stumped us is that periodically we need to *reprocess* the streaming part for certain entities from where the batch left off.

i.e

1. Imagine batch has processed events upto t1
2. Streaming is at t2 (t2 > t1)
3. we are reading from eventhub in the streaming pipeline

For most entities

1. we want to run the next micro-batch from t2
2. certain smaller subset we want to reprocess from t1

My idea was to get batchId/timestamp associated with the micro-batch when the event was last processed. I am hoping to say then that event-batch > batchId or event-receivedtimestamp > Lastfullyprocessedtimestamp to skip most events except the ones that I want reprocessed.

But I haven't found any way to find a timestamp of last process or batchId yet.

Have other people encountered similar scenarios? How do they go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> But I haven't found any way to find a timestamp of last process or batchId yet.

That should be part of [StreamingQueryProgress](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress), and `timestamp` looks like what you want.

> Beginning time of the trigger in ISO8601 format, i.e. UTC timestamps.

The last and recent `StreamingQueryProgresses` are available using [StreamingQuery.lastProgress](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@lastProgress:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress) and [StreamingQuery.recentProgress](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@recentProgress:Array[org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress]).